# WCF Windows service with an API to a windows form client, API return value tells me it could not connect to device. Whats the preffered way?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a WCF windows service which exposes an API to a windows form application.

API connection to client:

```
            var serviceType = typeof(Mail2SmsServerApi);

            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/");
            host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, new[] { uri });

            var behaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true };
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behaviour);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new BasicHttpBinding(), "Hello");
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), new BasicHttpBinding(), "mex");

            host.Open();
```

My ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Mail2SmsServerApi
{
    [OperationContract]
    public string Imei()
    {
        try
        {
            GSMHandler gsm = new GSMHandler();
            return gsm.GetImei();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogText.Error("API GetImei(), exception: " + ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

}

My GSMHandler class and method:

```
    public bool OpenConnection()
    {

        modem = new GsmPhone(_comport, _baudrate, _timeout);

        if (!comm.IsConnected())
        {
            try
            {
                modem.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogText.Debug("OpenConnection(), exception" + ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                modem.Close();
                modem.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogText.Debug("OpenConnection(), exception" + ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    public string GetImei()
    {
        string imei = "";
        try
        {
            imei = modem.RequestSerialNumber();
            LogText.Debug("IMEI:" + _IMEI);
            return imei;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogText.Error("Error caught in GetImei(), exception: " + ex.ToString());
            return imei;
        }
    }
```

When the OnStart method in my service are called, I'm opening a connection to the modem with :

```
                gsm = new GSMHandler();
                gsm.OpenConnection();
```

When OnStop are called, I'm stopping it with:

```
                gsm = new GSMHandler();
                gsm.OpenConnection();
```

My idea was that, with this design the service would handle the communication and the client and service could interact with the modem without getting a com port not open or com port busy problem. This is obviously wrong, since I'm not able to return values from the modem this way. It has to be a design failure from my side.

What I'm trying to achieve is that a client can talk to the modem through the service, and that not both of them make a direct connection to the modem. But that the service can handle the opening and closing of connection to modem, and pass commands in to the modem from the client...

So my question is, what's the appropriate way to design such a scenario? I'm not asking for the code, just how It's usual to design it...

I'm appreciating all answers :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have much more success if you performed the interaction with the modem as a single unit of work.

For example, design your service such that the caller calls a single method to send a text message, providing all of the necessary detail in the interface call.

The service method then performs all of the tasks necessary to open the modem, send the text message, and close the modem, in a single unit of work.

This design will allow you to ensure that the modem is always opened and closed correctly and completely within the unit of work instead of waiting for additional commands through the service that may never arrive.

Also, this design will allow you to eventually correctly support multiple modems, which your current design will not. You could have a modem pool and when a new request arrives, you could obtain an available modem from the pool, perform the unit of work, then return the modem to the pool on completion, even in a failure situation.

Comment: From the client i'm reading imei and signal strength from the modem, this is being done with a timer. The service are going to send the sms. So different work happens from both client and service at unknown times. I don't think this will help me? Or am I thinking wrong?